# How to avoid error to recognize hyphen with Mysql

Tags: mysql

How to avoid error to recognize hyphen with Mysql.I want to grant all privileges to database.There is a hyphen in the name of the database.But command doesn't work.

I tried back-quote and double-quotes.

```
grant all privileges on `hello-world`.* to 'user'@'localhost';
```

Command Succeeds

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/139433/grant-users-access-to-mysql-with-a-dash-in-the-database-name

Comment: Sorry,I solved.This is another problem.I forgot to add command ```flush privileges```